# Swift: Create Reproducible NSView using Interface Builder

Tags: swift, interface-builder, nsview

If I create a subclass of `NSView` like so:

```
class MyView: NSView {

    var field = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 35, 22))

    func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        field.stringValue = "Hello World"
        self.addSubview(field)
    }
}
```

... then I can create as many instances of this view as I want:

```
let view1 = MyView()
let view2 = MyView()

// ... more instances
```

... and do whatever I want with them:

```
view2.field.stringValue = "foo"

addSubview(view1)
addSubview(view2)
```

However, in reality I am trying to create a view that has many more than one `NSTextField` in it. And so figuring out what every single `NSTextField`'s frame should be is rather tedious, not to mention if I ever want to edit any of them things quickly become a mess. This is where Interface Builder comes in so handy. But I have never come across a way to use Interface Builder to create a declaration of a class. I have many times created a subclass of `NSView`, dragged a "custom view" into a nib file, added some things to the view, created some `IBOutlets` from the objects in the "custom view" to my subclass, changed the class of the "custom view" to my subclass, and everything works. But this is not recreateable (at least as far as I know). It is merely a specific instance of my class, initialized by IB, and that's it - there's only one instance. But what I want is a way to reproduce such a view. I want to be able to design a "template", so to speak, in IB, and then create several copies of that template. There must be a good way to do this. Perhaps with `NSViewController`? Any ideas?

Comment: You can deserialize a .xib file as many times as you want, and you get new, unshared objects out each time. Check out [`NSNib`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSNib_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNib).

Answer (score 0):

See this post for how to do nib instantiation in swift.
[Swift - Assign a NIB to self in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201249/swift-assign-a-nib-to-self-in-class)

My example below is deprecated, but still works just fine.
Here is a design pattern I've used about 50 times (in objective C) for this.
The key 'trick' is to call 'alloc' without 'init', like this example:

```
NSViewController *nibFileOwner = [NSViewController alloc];
NSArray *theTopLevelObjects;
[theMbRemoteControlListNib instantiateNibWithOwner:nibFileOwner
                                       topLevelObjects:&theTopLevelObjects];
```

Dealing with layout issues is still a pain, but at least the nib handles some of the issues.

In this particular example I am creating a comparison tool to compare a 'server A' config to 'server B' config.
This is just a skeleton of this implementation.

```
// subclass as NSMatrix to support drawing reuse of resetButtonCell (BGHUDButtonCell)
@interface MbRemoteControlList : NSMatrix <NSTextFieldDelegate, NSMenuDelegate, EditingAlignmentProtocol>
{
   NSArray                     *mTopLevelObjects;
   IBOutlet NSViewController   *toFilesOwner; // nib files owner
   IBOutlet NSTextField        *toFixNameText;
}

+ (MbRemoteControlList *)_privateCreate
{
    ////////////// BUILD MbRemoteControlList /////////////////////////////////
    NSBundle *theClassBundle;
    theClassBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSNib *theMbRemoteControlListNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MbRemoteControlList" bundle:theClassBundle];

    // A simple NSViewController is the nib 'File's Owner' so we can access
    // the MbRemoteControlList view in the nib hierarchy.
    NSViewController *nibFileOwner = [NSViewController alloc];
    NSArray *theTopLevelObjects;
    [theMbRemoteControlListNib instantiateNibWithOwner:nibFileOwner
                                       topLevelObjects:&theTopLevelObjects];

    MbRemoteControlList *newObj = (MbRemoteControlList *)[nibFileOwner view];
    if ( nibFileOwner != newObj->toFilesOwner )
    {
        DLogErr( @"MbRemoteControlList creation error");
        return nil;
    }

    newObj.mTopLevelObjects = theTopLevelObjects;
    [theMbRemoteControlListNib autorelease];
    if ( newObj.mTopLevelObjects )
        return newObj;

    DLogErr( @"MbRemoteControlList creation error");
    return nil;
}

+ (MbRemoteControlList *) create
{
    setupLayout();

    sLeftServer = [MbRemoteControlList _privateCreate];
    if ( !sLeftServer ) return nil;

    MbRemoteControlList *rightServer = [MbRemoteControlList _privateCreate];
    if ( !rightServer ) return nil;

    [sLeftServer setupWithRightServer: rightServer];
    return sLeftServer;
}
```

Related layout gak for this implementation:

```
// sLeftServer is the owner of the active server list
static MbRemoteControlList *sLeftServer;
static BOOL sIsComparingNow = NO; // true if side-by-side comparing with another servers prefs
static BOOL sInitDone = NO;

#define kPrefsUseSmallFont @"kPrefsUseSmallFont"
static BOOL sSmallSize = NO;
static int sOrigBaseWidth = 701;
// action menu items
enum
{
    kLargeFontSize = 1,
    kSmallFontSize = 2
};



typedef struct LayoutStruct
{
    NSControlSize controlSize;
    int rowHeight;
    int fontSize;

    int resetColumnWidth;
    int prefValueWidth;
    int contentWidth;
    int copyingControlsWidth;
    int scrollViewWidth1;
    int rightSideOriginX;
    int toCommandsPopupOriginX;
    int scrollViewWidth2;
} _LayoutStruct;
static LayoutStruct sLayout;

// layout constants
// preference name & value 250
// list view  250 + 20 = 270
// total window
// 6 + 270 + 60? + 282 + 18 + 6
//    #define kResetColumnWidth        20   // (needs to match value in nib + 1)
//    #define kPrefValueWidth          250  // (needs to match the nib)
//    #define kContentWidth            (kResetColumnWidth + kPrefValueWidth + 6)
//    #define kCopyingControlsWidth    120
//    #define kScrollViewWidth1        (kContentWidth + 18)
//    #define kRightSideOriginX        (kContentWidth + kCopyingControlsWidth)
//    #define kScrollViewWidth2        (kRightSideOriginX + kContentWidth + 18)
//
//    #define kDefaultRowHeight         20

static float sWidthFactor = 1.0;
#define textFieldStringWidth (int(100 * sWidthFactor))
#define textFieldFloatWidth  (int(40 * sWidthFactor))
#define textField5DigitWidth (int(39 * sWidthFactor))
#define textField4DigitWidth (int(33 * sWidthFactor))
#define textField3DigitWidth (int(27 * sWidthFactor))

void setupLayout()
{
    sSmallSize = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: kPrefsUseSmallFont] boolValue];
    if ( sSmallSize == YES )
    {
        sWidthFactor = 1.0;
        sLayout.controlSize          = NSSmallControlSize;
        sLayout.rowHeight            = 20;
        sLayout.fontSize             = 9;

        sLayout.resetColumnWidth     = 20;
        sLayout.prefValueWidth       = 250;
        sLayout.contentWidth         = sLayout.resetColumnWidth + sLayout.prefValueWidth + 6;
        sLayout.copyingControlsWidth = 120;
        sLayout.scrollViewWidth1     = sLayout.contentWidth + 18;
        sLayout.rightSideOriginX     = sLayout.contentWidth + sLayout.copyingControlsWidth;
        sLayout.scrollViewWidth2     = sLayout.rightSideOriginX + sLayout.contentWidth + 18;
        sLayout.toCommandsPopupOriginX = sLayout.scrollViewWidth2 - 224;
    }
    else
    {
        sWidthFactor = 13.0 / 9.0;
        sLayout.controlSize          = NSRegularControlSize;
        sLayout.rowHeight            = 25; // same as Director kValueEditorViewHeight
        sLayout.fontSize             = [NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize];

        sLayout.resetColumnWidth     = 20;
        sLayout.prefValueWidth       = 250 * sWidthFactor;
        sLayout.contentWidth         = sLayout.resetColumnWidth + sLayout.prefValueWidth + 6;
        sLayout.copyingControlsWidth = 120 + 8;
        sLayout.scrollViewWidth1     = sLayout.contentWidth + 18;
        sLayout.rightSideOriginX     = sLayout.contentWidth + sLayout.copyingControlsWidth;
        sLayout.scrollViewWidth2     = sLayout.rightSideOriginX + sLayout.contentWidth + 18;
        sLayout.toCommandsPopupOriginX = sLayout.rightSideOriginX + 8;
    }
}
```